# Inserting custom HTML into a SharePoint

Tags: html, sharepoint-designer

Where should I be entering custom HTML on a SharePoint page?

Should I be entering within a web part? Direct into SPD? Or using the "Edit Source" direct from within the page on the SharePoint site?

Or does it just make no difference?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want it to be easily maintain you should add a Content editor webpart to the page, and add the text in the webpart. (More here http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-foundation-help/using-the-content-editor-web-part-HA101794745.aspx)

Comment: Can I access that code from SPD? It doesn't seem to show up for me, the only way I can get direct access to edit it is from within the content editor which isn't the greatest editor.

Comment: You should try not to use SPD for stuff it is not needed for :) Are you doing very advanced `<div`markups, or what do you mean with not the best editor? If you want to add text, tables, images, links etc. you can use the RTE tools that you get in the ribbon when in edit mode of an content editor webpart. If you need more advanced stuff, build it outside of SP and add the source code to the HTML of the content editor webpart

Comment: Thanks. One last silly question, in SharePoint 2010 when I add a content editor web part within the properties I can see where the rich source editor is then underneath that the option to link to a text file. However in SP2013 when I add a content editor web part I only have the option to link to a a text file, there isnt an option to access an editor direct? Is the right?

Comment: You should be able to just Click in the webpart when in edit mode and then start typing :S

Comment: However did I not see that......? Thanks, all sorted now.

Comment: Glad to hear it worked out! :)